# How to get the total rotation angle by one finger touch in WinRT?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I am trying to make a dial control by following [Jerry's tutorial](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/12/walkthrough-building-sweet-dial-in-xaml.html). Because the method `GetAngle` is based on the position of the touch point, the calculated angle is always going to be equal or less than 360°. But what I need is if I spin the knot two and a half circles, I want to get `900° (360°*2 + 180°)`.

I know that the `e.Cumulative.Rotation` (`e` is `ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs`) can give me the total rotation angle, but looks like the rotation can only be triggered by two fingers.

Am I missing some easy solution here??

Comment: I think in this case you will have to track the finger movement and once it passes the starting point along the arc path, treat it as full circle movement.

Comment: @Romasz, this is the bit that I can't figure out. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spend a while on this and it turned out to be a nice program to play with ([thanks to Jerry for great blog post](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/12/walkthrough-building-sweet-dial-in-xaml.html)). At the end I've ended with little different solution - little below.

If you need to count the whole circles, then you need to remember the moment when the angle changes from 360 to 0 and remember that there was a full circle. In my example I'm remembering last quadrant and this helps me to handle the issue. The main code looks like this:

```cs
private Quadrants currentQuadrant = Quadrants.I;
private Quadrants lastQuadrant = Quadrants.I;
private double lastAngle = 0;

public enum Quadrants { I, IV, III, II } // counterclockwise quadrants
private double CheckAngle(Point touchPoint, Size bounds)
{
    // find point position relative to bounds
    double valX = touchPoint.X - (bounds.Width / 2d);
    double valY = (bounds.Height / 2d) - touchPoint.Y;
    // determine the quadrant and save it
    currentQuadrant = (valX >= 0) ?
        (valY >= 0) ? Quadrants.I : Quadrants.IV :
        (valY >= 0) ? Quadrants.II : Quadrants.III;

    double quadrantAngle = Math.Atan(valX / valY) * (180 / Math.PI); // calculate angle within quadrant
    return currentQuadrant == Quadrants.II ? 360 + quadrantAngle :
            currentQuadrant != Quadrants.I ? 180 + quadrantAngle : quadrantAngle;
}

private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double currentAngle = CheckAngle(e.Position, this.RenderSize);

    if (Math.Abs(lastAngle - currentAngle) < 1) return; // don't update UI always - performance

    if (currentQuadrant == Quadrants.I && lastQuadrant == Quadrants.II) // check for full circle
    { spinNumber++; RaiseProperty("SpinNumber"); } 
    else if ((currentQuadrant > lastQuadrant + 1)) return; // check if proper movement

    // update quadrants and Angle
    lastQuadrant = currentQuadrant;
    Angle = lastAngle = currentAngle;
}

private void Grid_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // reset all things
    Angle = lastAngle = spinNumber =0;
    currentQuadrant = lastQuadrant = Quadrants.I;
}
```

and some XAML part:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationCompleted="Grid_ManipulationCompleted">
        <Ellipse Width="300" Height="300" Fill="Red"/>
        <Path Fill="Green" Data="M 0 0 L 50 0 L 100 150 L 0 150 L 50 0 Z" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AngleTxt}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SpinNumber}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,25" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Note that this will work if you move your finger starting from first quadrant in clockwise direction. It also needs some more improvements, like handling the case when you move counterclockwise, especially change from 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: Thank you!! Using the quadrant is brilliant, this is enough to get me going.